# In-document highlighting hint for Kate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, kate

Is it possible to provide a hint for Kate which highlighting to use for a given document (inside the document itself) so that I don't have to set it manually? If so, in which syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a modeline. Kate has support for this. E.g. you can add this to your file:

```
# kate: syntax python;
```

See [here](https://kate-editor.org/2006/02/09/kate-modelines/),
[here](https://kate-editor.org/2011/07/23/kate-modeline-editor/)
or [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/config-variables.html)
for some documentation.